# How to return ONLY top 5% of responses in a column PANDAS

Tags: pandas

I am looking to return the top 5% of responses in a column using pandas. So, for `col_1`, basically, I want a list of the responses that make up at least 5% of the responses in that column.

The following returns the list of ALL responses in the `col_1` that meet the condition, as well as those that do not (returns boolean True and False):

```
df['col_1'].value_counts(normalize = True) >= .05
```

While this is somewhat helpful, I would like to return ONLY those that evaluate to true. Should I use a dictionary and loop? If so, how do I signal that I am using `value_counts(normalize = True) >= .05` to append to that dictionary?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If need filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['col_1'].value_counts(normalize = True)
L = s.index[s >= .05].tolist()
print (L)
```

Comment: Hi! I appreciate the response, but these both yielded the entire df, not just the top 5%. I am looking for a way to return ONLY the responses that make up 5% of the responses in col_1 (and nothing else). Does that make sense?

Comment: @Willy_Golden -  Need `s = df['col_1'].value_counts(normalize = True)` and then `print (s.index[s >= .05])` ?